# Performance testing using TFS 2013 regular version

Tags: performance, testing, tfs, visual-studio-2013

Could anyone please tell me if I can use TFS 2013 regular version to perform load testing or do we need to upgrade our version? If so what version that would be.

Answer (score 3):

You require Visual Studio Ultimate for performance testing. Note that it is **Visual Studio** and not TFS. You can get more details on the [Compare Visual Studio editions page](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-products-vs.aspx).